# CSS Overflow with two arguments

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, shorthand

I know that I can set horizontal and vertical scrolling behavior independently like so:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Can I combine these in shorthand CSS like so?

```
overflow: scroll hidden;
```

Is that valid? Is it supported?

Comment: _"Is that valid? Is it supported?"_ Nope.

Comment: a quick google search would have given you the answer. `overflow: scroll hidden;` is not equivalent to `overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: It was Google that made me wonder in the first place. I found a site that said I could, but when I tried it, it din't work. You say it's not equivalent. Do you mean it just doesn't do anything, or it does something else?

Comment: What was the site that said you could?

Comment: http://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/css_overflow.cfm See "Possible Values"